# Template parsing error while adding new component?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting template parsing error .I just add new `component` in main component.why ?

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/Dqr2n0rx3LODKt4NPUwk?p=preview

**error**

```
**zone.js@0.6.17:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'todo-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'todo-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'todo-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div><h1>My First </h1>[ERROR ->]<todo-input></todo-input></div>"): AppComponent@0:23 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:(…) Error: Template parse errors:
'todo-input' is not a known element:
1. If 'todo-input' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'todo-input' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message. ("<div><h1>My First </h1>[ERROR ->]<todo-input></todo-input></div>"): AppComponent@0:23
    at TemplateParser.parse (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:8525:21)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileTemplate (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16879:53)
    at eval (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16802:85)
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at compile (https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:16802:49)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:332:29)
    at Zone.run (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:225:44)
    at https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:591:58
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:365:38)
    at Zone.runTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser:265:48)consoleError @ zone.js@0.6.17:484
zone.js@0.6.17:486 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:(…)**
```

I just add new component this

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector :'todo-input',
    template:'<input type="text"/>'
})

export class Todo {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/eCRqpEzvMicKpiXdD1gp?p=preview

Just shifted **todo.input.ts** in to **app folder**

Then, imported **Todo** component and **declare** it within **@NgModule's declarations metadata** as shown below,

```
import {Todo} from './todo.input';       //<----added this line

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,Todo],   //<----added Todo
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```